# Как изменить action у формы поиска Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, form, action

```
$('#search_form').attr('action', '?tag='+USFedCourts+'+'+StateSupremeCourts+'+'+Courts);
```

В форме поиска чекбоксы, в зависимости от выбранных чекбоксов нужно изменять action у формы поиска.
Пытаюсь вот так с jquery менять динамически action. Кликаю - меняется. Но как только нажимаю кнопку отправить, переход идет по стандартному адресу, а не сгенерированному jquery. Где смотреть, на каком этапе wordpress подставляет свой дефолтный action?

Comment: Зачем вы меняете action? Добавьте в форму поля типа hidden и меняйте их.

Comment: А затем используйте фильтр - 
function search_filter($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
      $query->set('post_type', array( 'post', 'movie' ) );
    }
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filter');